# How to catch last update in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have three Google Forms which submit data to different sheet in Spreadsheet. Google Forms write time stamp in first column when data is submitted. My triggered function send the email notification on submit data to spreadsheet from GForm. I need a different content of notification depending on the sheet of the spreadsheet where data is submitted.

I think about this:

1. get last update of spreadsheet
2. switch first sheet to action sheet
3. find the date equals the last update data in action sheet
   if date is not founded, switch to next sheet and find last update date
   ...
   ...
   if date is founded
4. get name of action sheet
5. send content-associated notification

So, think it's too difficult. Of course I can create many spreadsheet with many scripts and each script will send different notification, but it is not ergonomic.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the event coming from your forms you can get the timeStamp and the row number where the response is recorded.  With both criteria I guess it shoudn't be too  hard to find the right sheet, just examine this row number in every sheet and compare the time values, if there is a match then you get it !

You can get the values in the eventinfo like this:

```
  Logger.log('row = '+e.range['rowEnd'] + ' timestamp = '+e.namedValues['Timestamp'] )
```

I didn't test further so please update here is it worked as expected (or not).

Comment: Thank you! I already get the timeStamp and lastRow. My first solution was like this: 1) get the lastFileUpdate 2) send notification with the lastFileUpdate. But it was wrong cause gForm is not update file. Google Drive change the update date only when user changed the file by UI of Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an onEdit trigger:

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet_name = s.getName();

    //you can also add a code to get row and col, timestamp, etc.
}
```

*Note: haven't tested this code. I assume this is what you want.*